# How to reload page upon error with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some times I get one of the following error when I load my html/javascript page:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

But, upon refresh, it loads fine. Is there a way, I can have the page automatically refresh if it gets this error in javascript

Essentially, I want the page to refresh if any error occurs.

Comment: Do you know which resource is giving the 403? Is it always a different one?

Answer (score 2):

I would focus your efforts on trying to fix the 403 issue rather than trying to detect and refresh.  You could be making the problem worse by forcing clients to refresh if it's what I think it is.  If you have mod_evasive installed on apache, or something similar, it could be returning 403 because it detects too many requests at once.

http://pr0gr4mm3r.com/internet/how-to-fix-random-403-errors/

Comment: I like that you tell the OP to deal with what might be the more important issue rather than trying to suggest how to program the requested workaround.

Comment: Sometimes 403s are legitimate: Forbidden RESTful replies when accessing web resources from Facebook, Twitter and stuff. When the oauth token is revoked, you need to treat application level 403s. Your assumption is very specific.

Comment: @cdanea it is still important to understand why and where the 403s are coming from. I don't get the impression that the OP has this information.

Comment: It may be out of his control. As a frontend developer, you do not always control what the server replies with, especially if it's an API server that you are subscribing to. He would open another question about why the server throws 403s if that's what he was interested in.

Comment: @cdanea this is all speculative, since the OP hasn't given enough information to adequately assess any of this. I think discussing hypothetical motivations in this case is not very productive.

Answer (score 0):

Use this before doing ajax requests with jQuery

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr) {
  if(jqxhr.status ===403) window.location = '/login/?error=forbidden';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try "try"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 try {
  //code
 }
 catch(err) {
  location.reload();
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:
Put onerror event for img tag and reload img (or even the page) if error occurred.

```
<img id="myimg" src="image.jpg" onerror="img_load_error()"/>

<script>
function img_load_error() {
  var myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
  var img_src = myimg.src;
  myimg.src='';
  myimg.src = img_src;

  //OR       

  //if you want to reload the page then just do:
  window.location.reload();
}
</script>
```